# jQuery file upload control submits large files erroneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I have a custom file upload implementation for the blueimp/jQuery file upload control.  It works great except when I choose multiple files and one of them exceeds the maximum length, it still attempts to upload the out of bounds file (even though I don't call `data.submit()` for that particular file).

I have verified the `progress` event doesn't fire for the large (and unsubmitted) file, but the server ultimately reports a 404.13 (The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length), and none of the other files that were actually submitted get uploaded.

How can I change the way I use the jQuery file upload control to upload the valid files, but ignore the large file?

Here is my code...it manipulates a model that is leveraged by knockout to display UI elements, so you won't see any UI manipulation in the code below.

```
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Handlers/UploadHandler.ashx',
            progress: function (e, data) {
                console.log(data.context);
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                var file = fileUploadDataModel.files()[data.context];
                file.percentComplete(progress);
            },
            add: function (e, data) {
                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    var fileModel = new FileModel(file.name, file.size);
                    fileUploadDataModel.files.push(fileModel);
                    data.context = fileUploadDataModel.files().length - 1;

                    if (file.size > opts.maxFileSize) {
                        fileModel.errorMessage('{0} ({1}) exceeds maximum size -- rejected'.format(file.name, friendlyBytes(file.size)));
                        fileModel.percentComplete(0);
                    }
                    else data.submit();
                });
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                var file = fileUploadDataModel.files()[data.context];
                file.percentComplete(100);
            },
            singleFileUploads: false,
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by marking the files that were invalid, removing them from the data.files array and then submitting the rest.  Here is the fixed code...

```
        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '/Handlers/UploadHandler.ashx',
            progress: function (e, data) {
                console.log(data.context);
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                var file = fileUploadDataModel.files()[data.context];
                file.percentComplete(progress);
            },
            add: function (e, data) {
                var itemsToRemove = [];
                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    var fileModel = new FileModel(file.name, file.size);
                    fileUploadDataModel.files.push(fileModel);
                    fileModel.sourceIndex = fileUploadDataModel.files().length - 1;
                    file.fileModel = fileModel;

                    if (file.size > opts.maxFileSize) {
                        fileModel.errorMessage('{0} ({1}) exceeds maximum size -- rejected'.format(file.name, friendlyBytes(file.size)));
                        fileModel.percentComplete(0);
                        itemsToRemove.push(index);
                    }
                });

                itemsToRemove = itemsToRemove.reverse();
                for (index in itemsToRemove)
                    data.files.splice(itemsToRemove[index], 1);

                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    data.context = file.fileModel.sourceIndex;
                    data.submit();
                });
            },
            done: function (e, data) {
                var file = fileUploadDataModel.files()[data.context];
                file.percentComplete(100);
            },
            singleFileUploads: false,
        });
```